# Popen xauth list

Tags: python-2.7, popen, xauth

I am trying to run a wxpython script via VNC. When i try to open it i get the error:

X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

I solve it via:

```
xauth list 
sudo xauth add raspberrypi/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
```

and then the corresponding cookie. Thing is i wanted to automate this in the init of the script, so that the user would not need to do it every time. i have written the following script:

```
import subprocess
import string

p=subprocess.Popen(['xauth','list'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out,err)=p.communicate()
out1=out.split('\n')
for line in out1:
 t=line.split()
 y=subprocess.Popen(['sudo','xauth','add',t[0],t[1],t[2]],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which works fine but i am still not able to get the program to run. Checking the output i realize that i am not getting the same output if i run xauth list from shell and if i run it with Popen.

Any help would be much appreciated!